# Should this debugging question be migrated to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

Should https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319117/how-to-generate-random-negative-biginteger-in-java/319119#319119 be migrated to stackoverflow?

It shows a clear goal and a failed attempt at a solution.  While I don't feel it's on topic here it seems a good fit for stackoverflow.

It has been closed as a debugging question.  If there is a reason not to move it to stackoverflow I'd like to know what it is.

Also wondering if I should have done more than point out that it was a stackoverflow style question in the comments.  Do we flag questions in need of migration?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I probably wouldn't have migrated because it's not a particularly good question.

Users with more than 3,000 reputation can vote to migrate (close -> off topic -> belongs on another site -> Stack Overflow). If a majority flag to migrate it gets migrated unless:

1. The OP is question blocked on Stack Overflow. Not even a moderator can migrate in these circumstances.
2. The OP hasn't used any tags that also exist on Stack Overflow. A moderator can migrate in these circumstances.

Users with less than 3,000 reputation can flag to migrate (flag -> off topic -> belongs on another site -> Stack Overflow). This puts the question onto the close review queue for 3,000+ rep users to handle.

Comment: 1) Are you saying this OP is blocked or is that just hypothetical?  2) What are "flags that also exist on Stack Overflow?" 3) If I had flagged this question that way would you have considered it helpful even if you didn't think it was migration worthy?

Comment: @CandiedOrange - 1 - hypothetical. 2 - I meant "tags". 3 - If you flagged it by the route I suggested I wouldn't necessarily have seen the flag.

Comment: 2 stackoverflow doesn't have a java tag? 3 if you had: helpful or not helpful?

Comment: @CandiedOrange - Yes SO has a "java" tag, I was just adding that for completeness. I probably would have marked it helpful - but please, please, *please* don't get hung up on getting all your flags marked helpful.

Comment: I have been entirely hung up on having them marked helpful.  I had no idea it was acceptable to be noisy with flagging.  Should I flag it now then?

Comment: @CandiedOrange - "noisy" isn't what we;re going for here. "Getting a few wrong" is probably closer to the mark. and no don't flag it now. It's closed & done.